# Automatically Match Exposure for non-RAW files

Tags: lightroom, exposure, automation

Hello i'd like to automatically match exposure of PNG, where there's no extra data except for the pixels,
how can I automatically match their exposure?

Thanks

Comment: Only in post? Are these photos of a series? Or across multiple shoots, locations?

Comment: You could compute the difference in brightness and adjust accordingly. See https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/104145/how-to-calculate-difference-in-exposure-between-two-given-frames/112673

Comment: Here's your problem in a nutshell: The brightest and darkest parts of the image will not necessarily change by the same number of stops when the overall brightness changes.

Comment: Also, you're wanting to match *brightness*, not *exposure*. Exposure is strictly the value of the combinations of sensitivity (ISO), aperture (Av), and exposure time/shutter speed (Tv). A given exposure value has nothing to do with how bright the scene is or how bright the result is .You can shoot under bright sunlight at ISO 100, f/2.8, 1/2 second and in a very dark cave at ISO 100, f/2.8, 1/2 second. One image will be pure white, the other will be solid black. Both were shot at EV 4. Both have the same exposure.